# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'block_end') CssSyntaxError - stylelint

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

trying to add linter to my project.Using sass.

I selected stylelint after a research.

Having that error when running :

```
npx stylelint "**/*.sass"
```

this is the code

```css
@import '../../../../sass/config/variables'

.settingsPage
  align-content: center
  background: #f7f9fc
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  height: 100vh
  margin: 0 auto

    .tabsNav
        padding-top: 0

.headerSection
  background-color: $header-section-color

.title
    color: $blue-gray
    font-size: 28px
    font-weight: 600
    margin-bottom: 60px
    margin-top: 20px

.warningContainer
    align-content: center
    display: flex
    justify-content: center
    margin-bottom: 30px
    margin-top: -52px

.tabContent
  background-color: $content-section-color
  height: 64%
  padding-top: 30px

.container
    overflow-y: scroll
```

couldnt find any reason for that error.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your Stylelint configuration, please?

Comment: const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
 "extends": "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines",
 "customSyntax": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/postcss-sass'),
 "rules": {
  "declaration-block-trailing-semicolon": "never",
  "block-opening-brace-space-before": null,
  "max-nesting-depth": 3,
  "selector-class-pattern": "",
  "color-named": null,
  "selector-no-qualifying-type": [true, { ignore: ["class"] }],
 },
 "ignoreFiles": ["**/index.sass"]
}